# Ansible synchronise module says --out-format is unknown option

Tags: rsync, ansible

I have a simple ansible playbook by which i want to rsync folders from target machines onto my ansible host.

```
---
- hosts: testServers
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  - synchronize: mode=pull src=/home/prod/live-tpb/log/ dest=/root/playbooks/backup_live_folders/logs/{{ ansible_hostname }}
```

but when i run this playbook, it errors out saying

> rsync: --out-format=<>%i %n%L: unknown option

The full error generated using the -vvvv option is as below.

```
failed: [192.168.101.174 -> 127.0.0.1] => {"cmd": "rsync --delay-updates -FF --compress --archive --rsh 'ssh  -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' --rsync-path=\"sudo rsync\" --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' \"ansible@192.168.101.174:/home/prod/live-tpb/log/\" \"/root/playbooks/backup_live_folders/logs/serverC6174\"", "failed": true, "rc": 1}
msg: rsync: --out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L: unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1231) [client=2.6.8]
```

When I run the command directly too this fails -

```
[root@server11 backup_live_folders]# rsync --delay-updates -FF --compress --archive --rsh 'ssh  -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L'  ansible@192.168.101.174:/home/prod/live-tpb/logs/ /root/playbooks/backup_live_folders/logs/serverC6174
rsync: --out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L: unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1231) [client=2.6.8]
```

This looks like it is a problem with rsync on 14.04. My host machine is RHEL 5.4 and target machine is ubuntu 14.04.

How do i disable the --out-format option from ansible? Has anyone else faced similar problem? If yes, how to work around this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It was a problem of version. Upgrading rsync on source machine from v2.6.8 to v3.0.7 fixed the issue.

Apologies for the question.